# Lucene How to remove an int field

Tags: lucene

I want to delete a document contains a certain number in a int field called "no". My code is

```
//add it before
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new IntField("no", number, Field.Store.YES));
w.addDocument(doc);

//bunch of code in the middle

// Now want to delete that doc
w.deleteDocuments(new Term("no", number)) // w is a IndexWriter
w.commit();
```

But the problem is Term only takes String as constructor. So should I convert int to String in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just delete using a `Query` instead of a `Term`.  Like this:

```java
Query deleteQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("no", number, number, true, true);
writer.deleteDocuments(deleteQuery);
```

You can convert an int to the indexed string representation using [`NumericUtils`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html), if you so desire (This wouldn't be the approach I would recommend though. This API, as noted in the docs, is intended for *internal use only*):

```java
BytesRefBuilder builder = new BytesRefBuilder();
NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(number, 0, builder);
writer.deleteDocuments(new Term("no", builder.toBytesRef()));
```

Comment: so for the IndexWriter, I set IndexWriterConfig to be config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.APPEND); Is that necessary to set the append mode? thanks!

Comment: @user2628641 - If you want it to `APPEND`, yes.  It will be `CREATE_OR_APPEND` by default.